# How to run async in consecutive order in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 $scope.SaveAuditItems = function (audit) {
    var isError = false;
    $scope.isProcessing = true;
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    for (var siteCounter = 0; siteCounter < audit.SessionSiteList.length; siteCounter++) {
        for (var itemCounter = 0; itemCounter < audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length; itemCounter++) {
            var item = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList[itemCounter];

            item.TotalItems = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length;
            item.CurrentItem = itemCounter;

            promises.push($scope.submitaudit(item));
        }
    };
     //It appears to be running all the promises in the array in parrallel then running CloseAudit.
        $q.all(promises).then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.CloseAudit(audit.AuditSessionId).then(function () {
            },
            function(){
                alert("done");
            },
            function(){
                alert("done");
            }
            );
        }).catch(function (exception) {
            $scope.Loading("Could not submit audit session #'+ audit.AuditSessionId +' , please try again.", 2000);
        });


}
```

How do make the promises run in consecutive order?  It causes race conditions on the server data is being submitted to?    This angular 1 code.

How do i use then when i do not know how many promises i will be running in sequence?   All other answers use then but are always predefined count of promises.  I cannot have a then within a then for ever..i can't seem to comprehend how i do this.

-------------------------------------edit 2---------------------------------------------

```
  $scope.SaveAuditItems = function (audit) {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>Please wait..Sending Item ( 1 Of ' + $scope.AuditItemCounter + ' )',
    }).then(function () {});
    var isError = false;
    $scope.isProcessing = true;
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    for (var siteCounter = 0; siteCounter < audit.SessionSiteList.length; siteCounter++) {
        for (var itemCounter = 0; itemCounter < audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length; itemCounter++) {
            var item = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList[itemCounter];

            item.TotalItems = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length;
            item.CurrentItem = itemCounter;
            // $scope.Loading('Sending Item ( ' + item.CurrentItem + ' Of ' + item.TotalItems + ' )..', 0).then(function () {

            promises.push($scope.submitaudit(item));



            ConsoleLogger.AddLog('Sent Item ( ' + item.CurrentItem + ' Of ' + item.TotalItems + ' )');

            //Loading.show({ template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>Sending Item ' + item.CurrentItem + ' of ' + item.TotalItems + ' ', }).then(function () { });
            $scope.Loading('Sent item ( ' + item.CurrentItem + ' Of ' + item.TotalItems + ' )', 0).then(function () {});


        }
    }

    var all = promises.reduce(function (cur, next) {
        return cur.then(next);
    }, Promise.resolve(true));


    all.then(function (a) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>Finalising your audit..'
        }).then(function () {
                $scope.CloseAudit(audit.AuditSessionId).then(function () {
                    ConsoleLogger.AddLog('Audit submitted successfully.');
                });
            },
            function () {
                alert("doneeee");
            },
            function () {
                alert("done");
            }
        );
    });
```

[image]

You can see in the timing that the promises are not running in sequence as expected?   What am i missing?  I made the promises with a timeout of 7 seconds..
The closeaudit should have run after all the promises had returned but not happening for me!

GOT IT WORKING BY CHNAGING
          promises.push($scope.submitaudit(item));
TO

```
 promises.push(function(){return $scope.submitaudit(item)});
```

Comment: Chain them using each promises `then(...)` instead of using `$q.all(...)`

Comment: how do i use then when i do not know how many promises i will be running in sequence?

Comment: are you able to show how i would use a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example how to do it. Reduce all promises from the array one by one, the reduce function will chain `then()` of each promise. It will start with first after the first has resolved it will call second and so on ... to the end ;].

```js
var promises = [
 function() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('resolve promise 1 after 3sec');
     resolve('promise 1');
    }, 3000)
  })},
  function() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('resolve promise 2 after 1.5sec');
     resolve('promise 2');
    }, 1500)
  })},
  function() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('resolve promise 3 after 2sec');
     resolve('promise 3');
    }, 2000);
  })}];

var all = promises.reduce(function(cur, next) {
    return cur.then(next);
}, Promise.resolve(true));


all.then(function(a) {
    console.log('all are done!');
});
```